# Select users I like using PHP

Tags: php

I need to make query using PHP from two tables. The first tables has users information such as (userName, age, country).

In my app users can like other users so I make the second table which has two fields (myName, userName) userName will be the same value as in the first table.

What I need is to select all users that I liked.

First Table:

```
userName    |   age |   country
--------------------------------------
name1       |   20  |   USA
name2       |   21  |   UK
name3       |   23  |   UAE
name4       |   33  |   India
name5       |   19  |   Canada
name6       |   25  |   USA
```

Second Table:

```
userName        myName
name1   |       ahmed
name2   |       Mic
name3   |       ahmed
name4   |       Danil
name5   |       ahmed
name5   |       Mic
name6   |       ahmed
```

From the above table you can see that Ahmed likes 3 user names. I need to use PHP to select the three users depend on a POST.

Thanks and I hope the question is clear

Comment: Are these database tables? MySQL maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your first table is called (users) and the second one is (users_likes), then you should have a query like this :

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_likes ul ON ul.userName = u.userName
WHERE ul.myName = 'ahmed'
```

Answer (score 0):

First: I'm assuming you're using a relational database like MySQL, if that's the case you're going about this problem incorrectly.

Why? What if a user i.e. John, likes Brandon and Jacob, but Brandon decides that his name needs to be Brando now (cause he has weird nicknames), the user Brandon will be removed from all future queries because his name has changed. OR What if there are two "Brandon Smith"'s in the database? You don't want to like both.

The way we get around this is by using associative tables and joins. This is why the primary key ('id') is so important in databases. This way as long as the user's id doesn't change (which shouldn't happen unless the user is deleted) we can keep the relationships.

```
Table 'user'
id    |  first_name  |  last_name  |  email  |
1     |  John        |  Doe        | a@b.org |
2     |  Brandon     |  Smith      | c@d.org |
3     |  Jacob       |  Smidt      | e@f.org |

Table 'user_like'
id    |  user_id     |  liked_user_id 
1     |  1           |  2
2     |  1           |  3
```

So you would select user and join user_like where user_id = user.id, and it would return all the user_ids liked.

It does create more work for you as far as queries go, but it makes for a more reliable database.